# ASP .NET - Submit on Enter - Prevent 'defaultbutton' when other button has focus

Tags: asp.net, .net, enter, defaultbutton

I have a search form consisting of the following...

```
<asp:Panel DefaultButton="btnSearch" ... >

    [...search criteria fields...]

    <asp:Button ID="btnReset" OnClick="btnReset_Click" ... />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" ... />

</asp:Panel>
```

The desired behaviour is that pressing the `Enter` key should invoke `btnSearch_Click` (which is working thanks to the `DefaultButton` attribute in the `asp:panel`)

The problem is that when `btnReset` has focus, pressing `Enter` should invoke `btnReset_Click` instead (which it doesn't - it's always `btnSearch`).

Is this easily achievable somehow, or am I going to have to hack up some bespoke JS to intercept .NET's `defaultButton` event handler?

Thanks in advance.

---

ETA: Here's a reusable solution I went with based on HenryChuang's accepted answer below.

1. Add a custom attribute `preventDefaultButton` to panels.

   ```
   <asp:Panel DefaultButton="btnSearch" preventDefaultButton="btnReset" >

       [...search criteria fields...]

       <asp:Button ID="btnReset" OnClick="btnReset_Click" ... />        
       <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" ... />

   </asp:Panel>
   ```
2. Run the following jQuery on pageload.

   ```
   $("div[preventDefaultButton]").each(function () {

       var div = $(this);
       var keypressEvent = div.attr("onkeypress");
       var btn = $("input[id$=" + div.attr("preventDefaultButton") + "]");

       btn.on("focus", { div: div }, function (event) {
           event.data.div.attr("onkeypress", "");
       });

       btn.on("blur", { div: div, keypressEvent: keypressEvent }, function (event) {
           event.data.div.attr("onkeypress", event.data.keypressEvent);
       });

   });
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the panel generate html

```
<div id="yourPanelClientID" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'btnSearch')">
```

so, when btnReset onfocus we break onkeypress event of Panel, add below to btnReset, 
remember when btnReset onblur, change Panel keypress to oringinal

```
onfocus="document.getElementById('yourPanelClientID').onkeypress = '';"
onblur="funA();"
function funA() {
        document.getElementById('yourPanelClientID').onkeypress = function () { return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, "btnSearch") };
    }
```

like this

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnReset"
 onfocus="document.getElementById('yourPanelClientID').onkeypress = '';" 
onblur="funA();"
onclick="btnReset_Click" .../>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I've edited my answer above to include a reusable solution based on your technique.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change `DefaultButton` attribute of your panel but this will work for only one at a time, better way would be to have Javascript to capture enter event and process accordingly.

One way can be having multiple panels, have a look at http://www.jstawski.com/archive/2008/09/23/multiple-default-buttons.aspx